# Count files in Folder by Python Programming

Tags: python, file, count, numbers, directory

I am trying to count number of files in my folder (/Home/python)
for that reason I make a short program

```
import os.path
path = '/Home/python'
num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

but it is given me an error like that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_number_of_files_folder.py", line 3, in <module>
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Home/python'
```

Guys can you plz help me to make it bug free program.
Thank You

[image]

Comment: I think it is absolute path , but exactly I don't know the definition absolute path but u can view /Home/python in my Question.. i just added that image

Comment: it is `home` lowercase h

Comment: H in uppercase ome are is lower case

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Actually it's /home/username/python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I also try with username but still same error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_number_of_files_folder2.py", line 4, in <module>
    num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Home/tansen/python'

Comment: @FahadUddin, look at the answer I provided, in particular the part about a lowercase `h`, if you print `os.path.expanduser("~/python")` you will see what I mean

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this instead

```
import os.path
path = os.getenv('HOME') + '/python'
num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

This is because you are not in /home/python. You are actually in your home directory which is /home/$USER/python. If you do the following, **in a terminal**, you will see where you are.

```
cd ~/python && pwd
```

Comment: Now it is giving that error

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "count_number_of_files_folder.py", line 2, in <module>
        path = os.env('HOME') + 'python'
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'env'

Comment: My bad, it is os.getenv(). It was a typo. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: yes ur new code is working perfectly now....
even i don't need to change the directly...
Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to be of service :)

Answer (score 12):

I think this is the easiest way:

```
import os

img_folder_path = 'C:/FolderName/FolderName2/IMG/'
dirListing = os.listdir(img_folder_path)

print(len(dirListing))
```

Comment: yes using the len - length on a object is the most effective way to get a count of a list.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be a lowercase `h` for ubuntu `home`and you also need to supply your username, so either use `path = "/home/user_name/python"` or `os.path.expanduser`.

`os.path.expanduser` will return something like `/home/username/python`:

```
import os
path = os.path.expanduser("~/python")
num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob, os
file_count = 0
WorkingPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(WorkingPath, '*.*')):
    file_count += 1
```

Just stick the source for that into whatever directory you are counting files in. This only counts files not folders.

Comment: where should I write my target path?

Comment: Won't this count one too many files if the program itself is in the directory?

Comment: start count at -1 or just replace WorkingPath with a path to whatever directory you want and run it from anywhere you want. This was just the quickest way I could come up with.

Comment: my workingpath is '/Home/python'
but it is not giving me right answer
can you plz put this path on right place of program to get the correct answer

Comment: @Fahad `/Home/python` is NOT the right path. Re-read Padraic's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27694862/2202669).

Comment: @fenceop yes u right, now its start working with '/home/tansen/python'
Thank You